# Why does output in an alternate-syntax switch statement cause a syntax error

Tags: php

I recently encountered the switch statement syntax error described at http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

My IDE (phpstorm) detected the error, but it didn't provide any useful context for correction.  The code certainly did produce a fatal error when including the file as a template.

The manual page's warning:

---

> **Warning**  Any output (including whitespace) between a switch statement and the first case will result in a syntax error. For example, this is invalid:

```
<?php switch ($foo): ?>
    <?php case 1: ?>
    ...
<?php endswitch ?>
```

> Whereas this is valid, as the trailing newline after the switch statement is considered part of the closing ?> and hence nothing is output between the switch and case:

```
<?php switch ($foo): ?>
<?php case 1: ?>
    ...
<?php endswitch ?>
```

---

The manual page offers no explanation.  Some user [comments on the page](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php#113902) don't explain anything either; they simply restate that whitespace isn't allowed.

Why is this a syntax error?

Comment: At least in my opinion, a question like this sounds to me like "why is `==` used for comparison", the answer is just "because the syntax is defined that way"...

Comment: I guess that's true, but the reason for the comparison operator is that the language needs one.  What's the reason for this quality of the syntax?

Comment: Short answer is because it'a syntax error .. But long anwser will be too long and precondition is Automata theory..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It just is.

It's a syntax error for the same reason that this is:

```
<?php

$foo = 1;
switch ($foo) {
?>
    This can't be here.
    <?php
    case 1:
        echo "I'm one";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "I'm two";
        break;
}
```

This results in:

> [27-Jan-2016 22:21:08 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '    This can't be here.', expecting case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT) or '}' in /path/file on line 7

The only thing that can follow a `switch` is a `case`. It's just how the language works.

The whitespace-specific limitation with the alternative syntax is one of the reasons that it *is* the *alternative* syntax: it results in ugly formatting and lacks indentation where one would normally expect to see it.

Comment: The non-whitespace example certainly makes it seem less crazy.  Is it that your example is tantamount to `switch ($foo) {
echo 'This can't be here.';
    case :
....` ?

Comment: @SethBattin Exactly. It's essentially the same problem.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: In general, anything between `?>` and `<?php` is like an `echo` statement. This includes whitespace.